# How can I keep ubuntu from syncing the clock?

Tags: 16.04, date, clock

I need to do some testing that involves setting the clock into the future, and I can't see how to disable ntp syncing with timedatectl or anything else so I can change the clock and not have it sync to real time.

This is ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stop and disable both `systemd-timesyncd` (installed by default) and `ntp` (if you have installed it). Better take a backup before moving the system into the future, because interesting things may happen when you will bring it back into the past.

```
sudo systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd && sudo systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd
sudo systemctl stop ntp && sudo systemctl disable ntp
```

If the system is a virtual machine you must also make sure that it is not set to synchronize its time with the host.